# Ionic 3: google map hides if background overwritten

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, sass, cordova-plugins, ionic3

So, ionic 3 has a good sass feature: overwriting variables [overwrite variable](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/). To customise my app, I changed `$background-color` on my own colour.

Then I needed to implement a google-map, so I installed [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) plugin. And when map was initialized I didn't see it. After looking for solutions I tried to change `ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor` to `transparent` and `none`, it didn't help. If I remove `$background-color` it appears in Android Emulator. In XCode emulator it doesn't. Tried to fix it also with `position:absolute` and `z-index`, didn't help.

home.html =>

```
<ion-content>

    <div #map id="map" style="height: 360px;"></div>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer no-shadow padding>
    <ion-toolbar position="bottom">
        <button ion-button block large upercase color="danger">cancel request</button>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

home.ts =>

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    NavController,
    IonicPage
} from 'ionic-angular';
import {
    GoogleMaps,
    GoogleMap,
    GoogleMapsEvent,
    LatLng,
    CameraPosition,
    MarkerOptions,
    Marker
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';


@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'home-page',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    constructor(public  navCtrl: NavController,
                public  googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {}

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.loadMap();
    }

    loadMap() {

        let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
        let map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);

        let pos: LatLng = new LatLng(31.771959, 35.217018);

        // create CameraPosition
        let position: CameraPosition = {
            target: pos,
            zoom: 14,
            tilt: 30
        };

        //create marker
        let markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
            position: pos,
            title: 'Hello'
        };

        // map ready event
        map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY)
            //move camera to position
            .then(() => map.moveCamera(position))
            //add a marker
            .then(() => map.addMarker(markerOptions),
                //show some info
                (marker) => marker.showInfoWindow());

    }

}
```

How does it look like? When I set variable `$background-color` other pages were changed. But map page is ...

Android emulator

[image: Android emulator]

iOS emulator

[image: iOS emulator]

Ionic info:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

android platform 6.2.1
ios platform 3.9.0
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0

Comment: not sure if it is related to your problem but `ion-footer` is normally after `ion-content`.. on the outside

Comment: @suraj good advice, thanks! but map is still the same :)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely caused because of how the Googlemaps plugin works. It doesn't embed a map in the current page, rather it is a completely separate Webview that is rendered beneath the Cordova Webview. For the map to appear, the plugin attempts to make all background of all HTML layers in the Cordova Webview transparent. Unfortunately, it doesn't do a very good job of it for Ionic.

Your best bet on iOS is to run on a device and debug in Safari, then inspect to see which class isn't properly being made transparent, then adjust your CSS accordingly, but this can get pretty nasty if the page you're displaying the map on is a part of a large nav stack.

Comment: it is a part of a stack pages... I also tried add an attribute with background to other elements such as selector `home-page` and `.ion-content` but I had the same result with map. I tried look for issue in Safari inspect element as well. And I'll try one more time. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [Google Maps Developer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions), you can try to set the "blue color" to the GoogleMaps' property `backgroundColor` to override the default background color, instead of using CSS to override background color.

I've faced the similar issue, and I am able to resolve it by removing the css background-color, and use the Maps API

In Ionic Native, it is the method `map.setBackgroundColor(color:string)`. You only can call this method once your map is initialised.

Hope it helps!

FYI: It is the property for "*color used for the background of the Map div*"